# What is the time complexity and memory footprint of dataframe operations in Spark?

Tags: time-complexity, apache-spark-sql, space-complexity, memory-consumption

What is the algorithmic complexity and/or memory consumption of dataframe operations in Spark? I can't find any information in the documentation.

One useful example would be the answer to the memory/disk footprint when extending a dataframe with another column (`withColumn()`): (in Python with automatic garbage collection) is it better to do `table = table.withColumn(…)` or does `extended_table = table.withColumn()` take about the same memory?

**PS**: Let's say that both tables are persisted with `persist()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning to the same variable or another variable doesn't make a difference. Spark just uses these assignments to build the lineage graph from your specified operation. When you invoke an actual Spark action the operations in the lineage graph are executed.

Additional memory is only needed when you cache intermediate results via `.cache()` or `.persist()`.

Comment: Good point. So my question would be more precise as: what happens if we cache both the original `table` and the extended version `extended_table`, in the case of `withColumn()`: do we have a _copy_ of `table`, or just a clever storage that knows that `extended_table` is just `table` plus one column?

Comment: [Internally](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.scala) `withColumn()` just calls the famous `select()` whose basic form always just operates on column collections and doesn't even have a notion of a whole table. This strongly suggests that the generated DataFrame is your clever storage. 
If you are still in doubt it should be easy to check the memory consumption of your DataFrame by looking at the [Spark Web UI](http://127.0.0.1:4040/storage/).